# Get index of item in dictionary by key in Swift

Tags: swift

I am doing this to loop through my dictionary until until I match the key. My dictionary is defined as [Int:String]

```
var index = 0
for (key, value) in mylist! {
    if key == property.propertyValue as! Int {
        // use index here
    }
    index += 1
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I see examples of filtering (something like the example below) but I am not sure how to make it work with a dictionary. Could I use something like this to find the index of the item? Or is there another way?

```
mylist.filter{$0.key == 1}
```

**UPDATE:**
This works:

```
let index = Array(mylist!.keys).index(of: 1)
```

But this doesn't:

```
let index = mylist!.index(forKey: 1)
```

It seems they both should work. I wonder why the 2nd one doesn't.

Comment: Dictionary keys are not ordered. It makes no sense to do what you are trying.

Comment: Why do you need an "index"? Why not simply use subscripting: `if let value = mydict[key] { ... }` ?

Comment: It seems you've posted an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question based on one of your comments to an answer below. You should redo your question to be about the actual problem you are trying to solve (setting up a picker view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could do it like so:

```
let myList = [
    2: "Hello",
    4: "Goodbye",
    8: "Whats up",
    16: "Hey"
]

let index = Array(myList.keys).index(of: property.propertyValue)
```

And then to find the key you're looking for again...

```
let key = Array(myList.keys)[index!]
```

As said in other answers, a dictionary is probably not the data structure you're looking for. But this should answer the question you've asked.

Answer (score 5):

A dictionary is an unordered collection type and doesn't have an index.

You can get the value directly by the key

```
let value = mylist[property.propertyValue as! Int]
```

Comment: A Dictionary is a Collection and therefore has indices :) There is even a `index(forKey:)` method.

Comment: A pseudo-index, Martin, since it conforms to certain collection protocols which maps the dictionary to a tuple under the hood.

Comment: I don't need the value. I only need the index so I can set my UIPickerView to the correct item. The for-loop works, but it seems cumbersome for what I need. I am setting my picker like this: picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

Comment: @Primico: That sounds as if you are relying on a certain order of dictionary entries. You probably should use an array instead.

Comment: In what way is `Dictionary.Index` a "pseudo-index" @vadian? For native storage at least, the index corresponds to the offset of the given bucket in the hash table. Sounds like a proper index to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given your dictionary

```
let dict = [1:"a", 2:"b", 3: ""]
```

you can extract the index of a given key (e.g. `1) simply writing

```
let indexForKey1 = dict.index(forKey: 1)
```

### Fetching all the indexes

You can also build a dictionary where they key is the index and the value is the key of dict

```
let indexes = dict.keys.map { dict.index(forKey: $0) }
```

> BTW: what do you **really** need to do?